# How do I add an events plugin to my customised theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I've just started working on a website that was built in Wordpress and highly customised and now I am trying to add an events plugin that needs to have our branding, but struggling.

All the page templates are in themes/my-theme/templates and then a folder called template-parts. I have duplicated a template and called it Events.

I have downloaded The Events Calendar plugin and have tried 2 things:

1. In Wordpress I have created a page and selected the Event template.
2. In the plugin settings section chosen the Events template.

Neither have worked. I also tried to copy their template code into my Event template, but I just get a spinning wheel.

Note: I have posted on their forum, but no response.

````
<?php
get_header();
?>
<section id="stories-of-success-intro" class="uk-section uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" style="z-index: -2; position: relative;">
  <div class="uk-container uk-text-center">
    <h2 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p>
     <?php the_field('intro_paragraph'); ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="white-paleblue-curve__spacer"></div>
</section>
<div class="white-paleblue-curve" style="z-index: -1"></div>
<section id="stories-grid" class="uk-section" style="padding-top: 20px; z-index: 1">
    <div class="uk-container">
     <?php the_field('content'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( '-1' );
}
get_header();
?>
<main id="tribe-events-pg-template" class="tribe-events-pg-template">
    <?php tribe_events_before_html(); ?>
    <?php tribe_get_view(); ?>
    <?php tribe_events_after_html(); ?>
</main> <!-- #tribe-events-pg-template -->
  </section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>```

I've managed to have the listing come up with the header and footer of the website, but I also what the template parts that lay on the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
````

Comment: ... and the "question" is?

Comment: How do I make the events appear instead of a spinning wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I wanted, but have found a work around.

I would have preferred having a page with the events on it, but for now I have copied over the entire plugin folder to my theme folder and added our formatting line by line to their default-template.